# How to move from one nib to another nib in iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

Hi i'm new with iPad. And I want to go from one nib to another when user press the button. How can i do that ?
I tried following but its not loading anything in spitview controller. Any sample code ?

```
 -(IBAction) goTo{
         NSLog(@"GO TO");
         GoFirst *go1 = [[GoFirst alloc] initWithNibName:@"GoFirst" bundle:nil];
    //     [self.navigationController popToViewController:go1 animated:YES];
           [self.navigationController pushViewController:go1 animated:YES];

         [go1 release];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GoFirst *go1 = [[GoFirst alloc] initWithNibName:"GoFirst" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:go1 animated:YES];
```